# How to detect swipe back event in iphone React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am developing a react native app, I am trying to clear setinterval function by backhandler event. It works correctly on android phone, but there is no back button in iphone, so I can't stop setinteval function. How can I detect swipe back handler?

[image: This is the behavior]

Comment: If sentInterval is specific for component then why don't you clear it directly on `componentWillUnmount()`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you are using `@react-navigation/native`. You can add Listener for `beforeRemove` event. This event is emitted every time the component is removed/user tries to leave the screen.

```
navigation.addListener('beforeRemove', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault()
    //clear setInterval here and go back
})
```

You can find more information [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-events/)

Comment: I understand your mean.
Can you help me remotely?
I will share my screen.
Please help me.

Comment: Where do I have to call this function?

Comment: you can call it inside `useEffect`

Comment: Hi, is there any way for react navigation v4? My project is old and it is using v4. Pls help if u know.

Comment: I have never tried this myself.. but you can try calling it inside `componentDidMount`. That might work.

Answer (score 2):

For me, this snippet is working fine. you can place this code in useEffect or componentDidMount. Make sure to cancel this event if you are navigation between the screens.

For reference, you can visit https://reactnavigation.org/docs/5.x/navigation-events
and select the react-navigation version according to your project.

```
const gestureEndListener = () => {
  console.log(" Called when screen is unmounted " )
}

useEffect(() => {
  const gestureHandler = navigation.addListener('didBlur', gestureEndListener);
  return () => {
    gestureHandler.remove();
  };
}, []);
```